# dnsmasq resolve DNS queries normally

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

I'm new to dnsmasq and networking isn't my strong point, hopefully i'm missing something simple.

I have a Ubuntu laptop running dnsmasq. The laptop's WiFi is connected to the Internet, the laptop's ethernet is connected to a LAN.

Plugging my machine into the LAN I am assigned an IP address by the laptop. Accessing www.google.com on my machine gets picked up the laptop and i'm served the laptops Apache page, which is my desired result. The problem is I can't access any other website, Destination Host Unreachable.

I'd like the laptop running dnsmasq to allow my machine to resolve DNS queries normally and only be restricted when accessing www.google.com.

My dnsmasq.conf is the default except:

```
address=/www.google.com/192.168.0.1
interface=eth0
dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h
```

I've a feeling it might be related to the IP settings on each network?
The WiFi has a static IP 192.168.1.55 taking to the router at 192.168.1.1 and the DNS server at 192.168.1.10.
The ethernet is configured manually with an IP 192.168.0.1 setting the router as the WiFi IP 192.168.1.55 and the same for the DNS server 192.168.1.55.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, this was related to iptables and not dnsmasq.